# Можно ли в Git вернуть незакоммиченные изменения?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-revert

Всем доброго времени суток.

**Ситуация такова:** с момента последнего коммита было внесено множество важных изменений. Эти изменения не были закоммиченны. По случайности был выполнен "Revert" к последнему коммиту и, естественно, изменения пропали.

**Вопрос:** можно ли каким-то образом вернуть все эти незакомиченные изменения, которые были до "Revert"?

Работаю с GIT через клиент GitKraken.

Comment: Кратко: если хотя бы делали `git add`, то можете восстановить файлы с потерей имен: `git fsck --lost-found`. А ещё вам может помочь кэш редактора или Ctrl+Z.